# Map Gully Depth for Ditches Extraction Whitebox

Tags: whitebox-gat

Is the Map Gully Depth open source (free)? or I should buy the Whitebox Licence to be able to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MapGullyDepth tool is not currently available in the WhiteboxTools open-core (https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/geospatial-software/) nor any of the Whitebox Extension products (https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/whitebox-general-toolset/). That tool resides within Whitebox-GAT, which is legacy software. However, we do plan to port this tool from Whitebox-GAT to WhiteboxTools in the future.

In the meantime, you can find some similar function to a degree in the  ImpoundmentSizeIndex tool, specifically the dam height output.
(https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/available_tools/hydrological_analysis.html#ImpoundmentSizeIndex).

Here is an example output of the ImpoundmentSizeIndex tool on a sample DEM, to show dam height.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have to extract the location of ditches in the agricultural fields and the roadside ditches as well. Would the ImpoundmentSizeIndex work for this case? If so, should I specify small thresholds for the Dam length?